# How to disable code cleanup in Tiny MCE Joomla 2.5 editor?

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.8

I need to disable the code clean up function in the **Tiny Mce** Joomla editor.

I have read some tutorials that say that I have to go in Extension ---> Plugin Managment ---> click on "Editor - TinyMCE" and here I have to disable this function in the basic configuration parameter, as you can see in this immage: http://www.microsoft.com/netherlands/Web/media/scenarios/codesnippets/joomla-tinymce.jpg

The problem is that I have not this parameter in my Tiny MCE plugin configuration !!!

Why? What can I do to solve and disable this function?

Comment: since Tinymce 3.4 there is no such option anymore

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to disable joomlas filtering. See the "Disable Joomla's filtering" section of [this page in the docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Entering_raw_HTML_in_editors)

Comment: mmm I still have some problem...if I am enter in Global Configuration and I go in "Filter Text" tab, so I have disabled the filter for all user groups (at the moment I am the only writer and this is not a big security problem...) So, now, if I create a new article and, inside it, I try to insert the following simple XML code: w3schools.com/xml/note.xml All the tag disappear and remain only the following text: ToveJaniReminderDon't forget me this weekend! that is the content of all XML tag of the previus example...

The only way that I have is insert before the Code HighLight tag:

Comment: {code class="brush: xml;"}CODE HERE{/code}

And leter, inside it, insert the XML code...so work and the XML is shown in the box...but all the code line are on the same line and so the code is unredable...